# Textblock, textbox text value does not show "-" char

Tags: wpf, textbox, key, textblock, accelerator

In my wpf application, textblock text property is binded to string property of an object.
String property value is "ABC-XYZ2014-HHH".

But neither textblock or textbox does not show the value correctly.
Value is displayed in textblock and textbox as "ABC-XYZ2014-"

I found that Label interpret "_" or "-" as  accelerator key but I am using textblock and textbox. But the value after the second "-" does not shown in the textblock and textbox.
I can see the correct value in MessageBox.

```
<UserControl x:Class="KaliteKontrol.PresentationLayer.Denetim"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:igEditors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"
         xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"
         xmlns:GridControlLib="clr-namespace:CommonLib.Utils;assembly=CommonLib"
         xmlns:commonLibUtils="clr-namespace:CommonLib.Utils;assembly=CommonLib"
         xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="RecognizesAccessKey" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <StackPanel  x:Name="mainPanel" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MainWindowsStyle}" >
        <Button>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Denetim.DRef}" />
        </Button>
        <Button IsCancel="True"  >

                    <AccessText Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Path=Denetim.DRef}"/>
        </Button>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Denetim.DRef}" Width="500"    />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Denetim.DRef}" Width="800"    />
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Denetim.DRef}"   />
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Thanks
Onur

Comment: It seems that it has problem with length of the String not '-' Character.

Comment: Just to start with something easy, are you sure your TextBox/TextBlock is wide enough, and that the value isn't just being cut off?

Comment: @Wonko I am sure the width is enough. To test I set the width as same as the screen width.

Comment: @Maryam the string property is set to have length 50 and it shows correctly in messagebox.show

Comment: Can you put the XAML part in the post?

Comment: I added part of xaml to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the end of the text in the `TextBlock` is getting cut off or hidden by something. You can verify this by adding a new `TextBlock` with the same text into a different window... you'll see that it works straight away. So the only question here is '*what* is hiding the end of the text?'

To find that out, simply set the `Background` property of the surrounding elements to various colours until you see something with one of those colours over the end of the `TextBlock`. You'll then know which element is hiding the end of the text.

You set the `Width` of the `TextBlock` and `TextBox`, but you *didn't* set it on the `StackPanel` or `ScrollViewer`. My guess is that your `StackPanel` is causing the problem because they are *not* controls that you can use to fit-to-size.

Comment: I set the backgrounds differently as you suggested. But I can not see any overlapped elements. I tried to insert image but It says I need at least 10 reputation :) So I added to image link :) http://i.imgur.com/Y8oRd54.png

Comment: Okey I found the problem. The value is changed in the view model. So it shows the correct value. I am sorry guys.